# How to get the type of something in Racket?

Tags: types, lisp, scheme, racket

Is there a way to get the type of something in Racket? (`#lang racket`, not `#lang typed/racket`)

Comment: The question marked as a duplicate does contain an answer to this question, but be sure to at least skim several of the answers, as some answers provide solutions for different Scheme implementations, some point out that there's no generic way to do this in Scheme, and some do include Racket-specific answers.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Thank you. Seems that there's no easy way to do what I want.

Comment: @Ben huh? use `(class-of)`, unless you MUST use `#lang racket`. Kind of the point of languages is to extend based on what you need, right?